# Error message Capybara::ElementNotFound when using css selectors with dom_id in Rspec testing with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, css-selectors, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using Rspec to test in Rails.  I'm trying to get the test to click on the edit button so that it can edit the todo list.  Since there are multiple edit links I added a dom_id in my index.html.erb file:

```
<h1>Listing Todo Lists</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @todo_lists.each do |todo_list| %>
      <tr id="<%= dom_id(todo_list) %>">
        <td><%= todo_list.title %></td>
        <td><%= todo_list.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', todo_list %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_todo_list_path(todo_list) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', todo_list, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Todo list', new_todo_list_path %>
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
  1) Editing todo lists Updates todo list with correct info
     Failure/Error:
       within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
         click_link "Edit"
       end

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "#todo_list_"
     # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:11:in `update_todo_list'
     # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my edit_spec.rb file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Editing todo lists" do
  def update_todo_list(options={})
    options[:title] ||= "My todo list"
    options[:description] ||= "This is my todo list"
    todo_list = options[:todo_list]

    visit "/todo_lists" 

    within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
      click_link "Edit"
    end

    fill_in "Title", with: options[:title]
    fill_in "Description", with: options[:description]

    click_button "Update Todo list"
  end

  it "Updates todo list with correct info" do
    todo_list = TodoList.new(title: "Grocery list", description: "This is my grocery  list")

    update_todo_list(todo_list: todo_list, title: "New title", description: "New description")

    todo_list.reload

    expect(page).to_have content("Todo list was successfully updated")
    expect(todo_list.title).to eq("New title")
    expect(todo_list.description).to eq("New description")
  end
end
```

There isn't a problem with my controllers or models because when I try to edit a todo list when the server is launched, it works fine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add `dom_id` to your question. Also, add `save_and_open_page` to your spec after `visit "/todo_lists"` and see what ID is actually being put in to the page.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it once I get home around 6 @Dave Schweisguth

Comment: I changed my edit_spec file so now it gives the new article an id of todo_list_1.  I made sure of that by using save_and_open_page, but now the error message says 'code' unable to find css "todo_list_1" 'code' which makes no sense because that is the exact id that I get when I use the method you said.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had forgotten to put a # in the css selector so it wasn't working, but now it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you only called `new` on your model, it wasn't saved and therefore there isn't an `id`. That's why error is saying:

```
Unable to find css "#todo_list_"
```

Thus you must save your model so that it'll have an `id` to be interpolated on the selector.

```
it "Updates todo list with correct info" do
  todo_list = TodoList.create!(title: "Grocery list", description: "This is my grocery  list")
  ...
```

Comment: I'll also try that once I get home around 6, thank you @Cristiano Alencar

Comment: Before I had not even been creating a new article so the .create! method worked for that, but when I run the test it gives me the same error message except it says it can't find "todo_list_1" but when I check the page source with save_and_open_page it says that the article has that exact id

Comment: nevermind I forgot to put a # before the within css selector, thank you very much!